# html5 cache manifest compatibility with head.js?

Tags: html, caching, head.js

There are large speed benefits to using head.js in my own sites. Now I am considering HTML5 cache manifest to improve offline access to sites and improving speed (more things are loaded from cache)
Are the benefits of head.js still there (parallel script loading in particular) if I use HTML5 Cache Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You will still get that head.js speed benefit during the initial cache manifest download event and during cache manifest updates